# EF Core 3.1 - Unit Testing a call to a context that returns null

Tags: entity-framework-core, moq, asp.net-core-3.1, xunit

Using Xunit and Moq, I am attempting to write a unit test to test that the following code block will log an error when the call to the context returns null.

```
                var entities = await _context.Charges
                .Select(c => chargeDTO.FromEntity(c))
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (entities == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Entities not found.");
                return null;
            }
```

I'm creating an in-memory database context for the unit tests, but the issue is that I can't work out how to mock the call to the context so that it returns null. The closest I've been able to get is having it return an empty collection. Is what I'm attempting actually possible, or am I trying to force a square peg through a round hole?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After further googling it appears that what I am trying to do is impossible. As per this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/

> If a query returns no rows from the database, the result will be an empty collection, rather than null.

Therefore I should be checking for an empty collection instead.

```
if (entities.Count == 0)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Entities not found.");
            return null;
        }
```